# Flutter permission_handler : request location permission on iOS

Tags: flutter, location

I want to ask user to enable permission only if he denied the permission or the permission is not allowed
This function is working very well on android

```
  Future _getLocationPermission() async {
    if (await Permission.location.request().isGranted) {
      permissionGranted = true;
    } else if (await Permission.location.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
      throw('location.request().isPermanentlyDenied');
    } else if (await Permission.location.request().isDenied) {
      throw('location.request().isDenied');
      permissionGranted = false;
    }
  }
```

but on iOS it throw exception permission isPermanentlyDenied
Unhandled Exception: location.request().isPermanentlyDenied
even if the user allowed location permission while using app
I'm using [permission_handler package](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

Answer (score 3):

iOS is stricter, it does not allow you to request for permission if the user has already permanently denied it. In this case your only option is to inform the user about this, and offer the possibility to open application settings and grant permission there. This will likely restart your application if the user grants.

So check the status without requesting:

```
final status = await Permission.location.status;
```

If status is permanently denied, display a Flutter dialog (you can't use the system permission grant dialog in this case):

```
if (status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
  // display a dialog, explain the user that he/she can grant 
  // permission only in the phone's application settings
}
```

If the user want's to do it, you can route to the application settings:

```
openAppSettings(); // this is a method of the permission handler package
```

This method is a future, but in my experience you don't need to await it.

Comment: The code in this condition 'if (await Permission.location.request().isPermanentlyDenied)' always execute  even if user allowed permission

Comment: Correct, if you await `request()` it will be executed, and will return a `PermissionStatus`, for example `Permission.location.request().isGranted` is a `Future<bool>` that will be true if permission is already granted.

Answer (score 1):

> This is just a function that returns bool if the user enables location
> or not simple

```
Future<bool> canGetLocation(Location location) async {
      if (!await location.requestService()) return false;
       final status = await location.requestPermission();
       final granted = PermissionStatus.granted;
       final grantedLimited = PermissionStatus.grantedLimited;
       bool result = status == granted || status == granted;
      return result;
    } 
    
    if (await canGetLocation(location)) {
         // Do something
        } else {
          final status = await handler.Permission.location.status;
          if (status.isPermanentlyDenied || status.isDenied) {
           // ask the user to open the app setting 
           // from permission handler package you have 
               openAppSettings(); 
          } else {
            // show info dialog or something that the user need to enable location services
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps mentioned in the [README.md](https://README.md)

check the location service is enabled or not (Settintg > Privacy and Security > location service). This worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [link](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/README.md). You must have to mention permission in POD file also.